# Relationship between multiple tables and a common table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables

- JobType
- JobSubType
- JobSubSubType

All tables take in parameters which are stored in the Parameter table.
Once a parameter is used in one table it cannot be used by any other table.

The Id values of all tables need to be present in the Parameter table. 
I created `EntityId` and `EntityType` columns in Parameter table which stores a `JobType` or `JobSubType` or `JobSubSubType` Id and the type of the entity.

How do I define relationships which ensure the values in `EntityId` belongs to `JobType`, `JobSubType` or `JobSubSubType`?

Simply having foreign keys on `EntityId` doesn't help. 
I do not want to create separate columns for `JobType` `JobSubType` or `JobSubsubType` Ids, as 2 columns out of 3 are always going to be null.

Example Parameter Table

```
+-------------+----------+---------------+--+
| ParameterId | EntityId |  EntityType   |  |
+-------------+----------+---------------+--+
|           1 |        2 | JobType       |  |
|           2 |        6 | JobSubType    |  |
|           3 |       11 | JobSubSubType |  |
|           4 |        4 | JobType       |  |
|           5 |        6 | JobType       |  |
|           6 |       12 | JobSubSubType |  |
+-------------+----------+---------------+--+
```

I had created  foreign keys on the JobType, JobSubType and JobSubSubType tables with EntityId. When I was inserting values for JobSubSubTypes in parameter table I got an error.

Comment: Provide some sample data and expect result. that really help. Sample data provide text format instead of image.

Comment: Are Job Type \ Sub Type \ etc related (ie is there a singular job they're all linked to?)  If not I'm kinda lost on what you want to be the unique element as far as "paramater" goes.  Like with the parameter itself be unique?  or what specifically can't be duplicated?

Comment: @MasonStedman Yes they are related. A JobType can have multiple JobSubTypes and a Job SubType can have multiple JobSubSubTypes.
Each of these will have their own parameters. So a parameter of JobSubType cannot be reused by  JobSubSubType even if the values are exactly the same. It will be a new parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in two ways. First way would be to have a common base table of types that is used to serve the three tables with a common ancestor ID and thus each table would have IDs that are unique across all three tables, and you could then reference the ID in one column, with perhaps a second column to indicate which table was referenced.

I believe this second approach would be preferable: Have only one types table, but use a ParentID as a self pointer to allow for sub types, sub sub types, and indeed sub sub sub sub sub sub sub sub sub types. Then all you need do is reference the ID.

To keep the existing IDs (as asked in the follow-up comments, you add an additional field identifying the table - as mentioned in the first paragraph. The join would then play out like follows:

```
SELECT
    col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM
    mytable1
    INNER JOIN types on mytable1.typeID = types.ID AND mytable1.typetable='Type'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM
    mytable1
    INNER JOIN types on mytable1.typeID = types.ID AND mytable1.subtypetable='SubType'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM
    mytable1
    INNER JOIN types on mytable1.typeID = subsubtypes.ID AND mytable1.typetable='SubSubType'
```

Comment: Is there a way we can use the same Ids. 
Option 2 cannot  be done because of the impact it will have on project. 
Options 1 seems feasible but still the changes required involve a lot of rewrite. 
In fact not having any constraints on Db and just having them on the application layer is a relatively easier option that I am considering if there is no way to keep the ids

Comment: The way to keep the same ids, i.e. keep the existing independent ids from the existing three tables, is to use two columns to make the join. he first column defines the table and the second the id. I will amend the answer to provide an example.